# Что и в каком порядке нужно учить в программировании на Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я абсолютно сбился с пути и не знаю как продолжать обучение.Подскажите пожалуйста что стоит изучить для программиста уровня (super)junior.Может быть литературу почитать какаю-нибудь или курсы есть? (желательно бесплатные)

Comment: https://github.com/GnuriaN/Python-Roadmap

Answer (score 1):

Тебе легче будет скачать приложение SoloLearn (андроид и ios) и учить там. Там вся информация даётся упорядоченно от легкого к сложному + есть задания, которые помогают закрепить изученный материал.